# debug module not working in event page after enabling the "storage" permission

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a very simple Chrome extension with an event page that uses the [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) module:

```
localStorage.debug = '*';

var debug = require('debug')('test');
debug('Test message');

console.log('debug:', localStorage.debug);
console.log('enabled:', debug.enabled);
```

In my manifest, I have:

```
"permissions": ["storage"],
"background": {
  "scripts": [
    "main/build.js"
  ]
},
```

When I inspect the event page, the output is:

```
debug: *
enabled: false
```

However, if I change the permissions to:

```
"permissions": []
```

And reload the extension, the output is:

```
test Test message +0ms
debug: *
enabled: true
```

**Why does that happen?**

---

I created an [archive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1trOTs4tzMx6lQfVX2YhjsLAUCGn2Ar8g/view?usp=sharing) with the extension. Feel free to extract it and load the extension as unpacked in Chrome to see the problem for yourself.

Comment: I’m not getting any values. I just want to print a debug message to the screen. I enable the `storage` permission, but I don’t use `chrome.storage.local` anywhere. The message appears when I remove `storage` from the permissions, without doing anything else. Therefore, the problem is not in the code at all. Not the code I wrote, at least.

Comment: That file is a bundle. Bundles are made up of my code and other people’s code. In this case, it’s my code and the debug module’s code. The code you saw is being used by the debug module, as I stated in my answer. You were right about the reason it doesn’t work, though.

Answer (score 1):

Upon digging in the debug module’s source code in `build.js`, I found:

```
exports.storage = 'undefined' != typeof chrome
               && 'undefined' != typeof chrome.storage
                  ? chrome.storage.local
                  : localstorage();
```

So apparently it detects if `chrome.storage.local` is available and uses *it*. There is an [issue](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/pull/476) about that in the module’s GitHub repository.

However, `chrome.storage.local` is asynchronous and the module appears to be using it in a synchronous manner, which is why it doesn’t work.

Turns out to be a fault in the debug module.